# How do I write to my Macintosh HD partition?

Tags: filesystem, macbook

I have Ubuntu dual booting on my macbook. When I tried to move a file from my home folder to a folder on the mac file system it wouldn't work. In the shell I get this error

inter-device move failed:

```
`foo' to `/media/Macintosh HD/home/foo'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system
```

Comment: IIRC you can't write to the HFS filesystem

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked and answered on Superuser [How to mount a HFS partition in Ubuntu as Read/Write](https://superuser.com/questions/84446/how-to-mount-a-hfs-partition-in-ubuntu-as-read-write)

Can you follow the answer there and let us know if it solves your problem?